# android Tab icons don't show up

Tags: android, tabs, icons

Right now I'm trying to get the Tab layout to work. I've done everything just like in Android TabView tutorial, app runs ok, but the problem is that I dont see any icons that I've defined them in ic_tab_artists.xml. There is text only.

I guess it has something to do with theme that is default one or style or whatever. I've tried to change it but it didn't help at all, still just a text.

I'm using Android SDK v4.03.

I'm sure there are enough Android gurus that will help, so thanks in advance.

This is my .xml defining using icons:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_grey" 
      android:state_selected="true" /> 


    <!-- When not selected (default), use white-->  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_white" />

</selector>
```

And my main HolePage Activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HolePage extends TabActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hole_page);

    //TABS      

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HolePageScores.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("scores").setIndicator("Scores",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_scores_icons))
                  .setContent(intent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs - Info
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HolePageInfo.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator("Info",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_scores_icons))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs - Top
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HolePageTop.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("top").setIndicator("Top",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_scores_icons))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs - Hole
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HolePageHole.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("hole").setIndicator("Hole",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_scores_icons))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs - Par
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HolePagePar.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("par").setIndicator("Par",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_scores_icons))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Set default tab2
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

}

}
```

Comment: can you post your code? you can set your icons by code only.. have you done that?

Comment: Sure, if you mean .xml that defines which icons to load and when>

Comment: please edit your question and put code there!

Comment: and also post your code in activity!

Comment: Well, my code is the same as this one (except files titles): http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: The same code worked for me.Please check do you miss anything there or not? try cleaning and bulding project.

Comment: Do you get class is deprecated information when you extend your main activity extends TabActivity? May this be a problem? Do you get exactly the same tab style as in that tutorial?

Comment: No..I dont get! which is the api level you are using?

Comment: Ive edited question. I use API 15.

Comment: This is how it looks on me: http://postimage.org/image/ceyrnvukz/

Comment: It is deprecated in 15 level but still it must not be creating problem,it works though.I didn't try in 15 level,i used in api level 7.

Comment: I did the same thing and it worked.sorry,i am not able to figure out what problem may be. tab_scores_icons is your selector xml file,right?

Comment: yes, tab_scores_icons is my selector. I will try another API. Thanks anyway for effort.

Answer (score 4):

without knowing much in depth about themes, i have discovered that specifying the theme `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` in the application manifest solves the issue and the icons show up in the tabs.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
    >
    <!-- MANIFEST -->
</application>
```

Hope, that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Also helped me. The strangest thing was - the app worked fine on android 2.3.