# Android icons do not show

Tags: android, drawable, android-icons

I try using Icons on several places in my app with the following code

```
    android:icon="@drawable/app_logo" />
```

but neither do they do show up nor do I get an error/warning.
I put app_logo.png into the res/drawable folder, then into any other drawable folder (res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-ldpi...) but the app_logo won't show up in my app. 
Can somebody please help me trace down the error?

edit: I want to use them in a menu and in a tab view, taken from online examples like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/help_logo" />
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="Help Text" />
<item android:id="@+id/icontext"
    android:title="App Logo Text"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_logo" />
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't get why someone would upvote that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `android:icon` in "several places". Or, technically, you can, however it would only make sense to use this within elements that supports `android:icon` attribute, otherwise it will just be skipped.

**EDIT**

`android:icon` for menus will appear for 6 menu items on Android 2.x (or 5 if you got more than 6 as 6th position is taken by system in such case, to let you expand menu more) and earlier, once user hit menu button. It will not appear if your menu got more items. It will also not appear if your device is running Android 3.0 and up. I'd recommend abandoning menus and switch to action bar pattern

Comment: "several places" might have been a bit too vague. The code I used is taken from tutorials and documentation so I guess that is not the problem... I also tried icons that work in other example-code but they just won't show up in my app.

Comment: hm... maybe I misunderstood the Android doc at that point http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html where they state that android:icon is A reference to a drawable to use as the item's icon - I cannot see where it has been deprecated?!

Comment: It is not deprecated, as it will work. However it will work as I wrote above. Do not learn 2.x - it is fading away

Comment: I understand. But I am just curious still why no icon will show up. Neither in my Tabs (I have 3 tabs) or in my Menu.xml (where I wanted to test one icon. The example code for the icon view worked on my device, icons were shown. But not in my project. But I will definitely look into ActionBar.

Comment: I found the problem in my case and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what's the problem thanks to [android Tab icons dont show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225868/android-tab-icons-dont-show-up)

My app still had the title bar - adding

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

to the manifest solved everything. Would be curious though how it would be possible to keep both the TitleBar and the icons.