# tabhost /tabbar icons not showing

Tags: android, xml, icons, android-tabhost, tabbar

my tab bar icon wont show up

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec barcodeInsertSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Barcode Insert");
barcodeInsertSpec.setIndicator("Barcode Insert", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home2));
barcodeInsertSpec.setContent(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BarcodeInsertActivity.class));

tabHost.addTab(barcodeInsertSpec);
```

drawable/home2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- When not selected, use that-->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/home22" />
    </selector>
```

and  put picture in three folders in different sizes (48x48, 32x32, 24x24) drawable-hdpi 
, drawable-ldpi, ... as .png

like drawable-hdpi/home22.png

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item  android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button0_click"></item>
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button0_click"></item>
    <item
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button0_click" />
     <item 
            android:drawable="@drawable/button0"></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: all buttons look different

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me :)

```
Resources res=getResources();
TabHost Tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
Tabs.setup();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
spec = Tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec.setIndicator("Home", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
Tabs.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use the drawable selector file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/select" />
  <item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/deselct" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Xamarin.

<strike>This was a hack solution that shows the icon but NOT the text (looks like an android defect):</strike>

- [tab-layout-wont-show-tab-icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665232/tab-layout-wont-show-tab-icons) - read the partial solution by Riandy

This solution shows both, but it hosed my app-wide styles, which indicates to me that I could probably set up a style override:

- [android-tab-icons-dont-show-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225868/android-tab-icons-dont-show-up?rq=1) - read the partial solution by noshky
- [Android theme guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

**EDIT 10 OCT 2013 - I got it to work in c#!**
*It should be straightforward to do the same in java*

I was able to get tabs to show up with icons with code and a custom style.  See below

**tab_indicator_holo.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_host_default_height"
android:orientation="horizontal"
style="@style/TabBlood"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    style="@style/TabTextBlood" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Activity OnCreate:**

```cs
...
var spec = this.TabHost.NewTabSpec(tag);
var drawableIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(drawableId);
View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab_indicator_holo, this.TabHost.TabWidget, false);
TextView title = tabIndicator.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Title);
ImageView img = tabIndicator.FindViewById<ImageView>(Android.Resource.Id.Icon);
title.Text = label;
img.SetImageDrawable(drawableIcon);
spec.SetIndicator(tabIndicator);
spec.SetContent(intent);
this.TabHost.AddTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
  TabHost th = getTabHost();
  TabHost.TabSpec sp;
  sp=th.newTabSpec("tab 1");
  sp.setIndicator("Home");
  sp.setContent(new Intent(this, Welcome.class));
  th.addTab(sp);
  tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOURIMAGE);
```

*You can also use a custom item selector in place of drawable to make a focused and pressed effects.
Cheers!

Comment: Hey, this may be a great solution - but could you give a bit of explanation about which bits you changed and why? don't forget - lots of newbies come to Stack overflow too, and they might not notice what is (for you) an obvious change.