# Android button highlighted state not working

Tags: android

I am using below code to display highlighted button when i am in that home page but blow my code is not working so I am not understanding what is the wrong in my xml code.

Can you tell me the correct way please?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
 <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_button" android:state_hovered="true"/>
 <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088465/tabhost-tabbar-icons-not-showing/15089448#15089448

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- pressed -->
</selector>
```

Comment: xml code is like this <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_home_display"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/displayButton_string"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
           android:textColor="@color/white" 
            android:textSize="19sp" />

Comment: where you add selector.xml

Comment: i kept it in drawable folder, is there any difference for heilighting the button in normal Activity and FragmentActivity

Comment: Any how thanks a lot for your support. I solved my problem using this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state

Answer (score 0):

create xml selector file.

```
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```