# Tab layout won't show tab icons

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I finally made a tab layout for my app that works flawlessly, but there's something missing. I also put a lot of effort in designing icons but I noticed that they're not showing at all. I'll post the code below to show how I tried to do it.

The whole java code (this is all withing onCreate):

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    //CRAFTING TAB
    TabSpec craftTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Crafting");
    craftTabSpec.setIndicator("Crafting", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.crafticonstate));
    Intent craftIntent = new Intent(this, Bifrost.class);
    craftTabSpec.setContent(craftIntent);

    //ADDITION INFO TAB
    TabSpec infoTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info");
    infoTabSpec.setIndicator("Info", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.infoiconstate));
    Intent infoIntent = new Intent(this, Bifrostinfo.class);
    infoTabSpec.setContent(infoIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(craftTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(infoTabSpec);
```

crafticonstate XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/weaponsmith_logo_hover"
      android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/weaponsmith_logo" />
</selector>
```

I also tried to add icon without the xml file, simply like 'R.drawable.icon' but that doesn't work either.

Comment: That looks alright. Can you please post how you declare `tabSpec` and how you add it to the `tabHost`?

Comment: @neo108 I posted the whole java code as you asked, please check my original post edit

Comment: Again, your code looks alright. And I am assuming your class is extending `TabActivity`?

Comment: @neo108 Yeah, it's extending TabActivity

Comment: Hmm. Any logcat errors relating to the `drawable`? Perhaps to troubleshoot, you could add a dummy layout with an `ImageView` with the src to the `R.drawable.crafticonstate` and see if the icon shows up.

Comment: @neo108 No logcat errors, I've never before worked with dummies, could you give me some pointers on how to do that?

Comment: What I mean by dummy is to create a layout just with an `ImageView` to test if the image shows up.

Comment: @neo108 I already have that, I have a layout that's showign two image views and it works just fine

Comment: Is `crafticonstate.xml` in a `drawable` folder along with the icons? Sorry to ask this many questions, your code looks alright but there is something wrong somewhere else I think.

Comment: I know, I'm thankful for your help. Yes, the crafticonstate.xml is in drawable-hdpi (same as the 2 icons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one nice trick that I used.

Unfortunately since TabHost is depreciated, it somehow only show text in the screen on higher level Api. Some workaround is to do this:

```
   //CRAFTING TAB
    TabSpec craftTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Crafting");      
    craftTabSpec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.crafticonstate));
    Intent craftIntent = new Intent(this, Bifrost.class);
    craftTabSpec.setContent(craftIntent);
```

Deleting the indicator(text), force the tab to load the images. if you still want the text. you can modify your image to include the text.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Icon looks much better than text anyway so I'll just keep it like this for now. Maybe in near future I'll figure it out how to keep text & image, but for now this is fine :)